# R filter_at: remove rows with specific multiple columns with only NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, na

I got a dataframe (dat) with 64 columns which looks like this:

```
   ID A  B  C 
   1  NA NA NA
   2  5  5  5
   3  5  5  NA
```

I would like to remove rows which contain only NA values in the columns 3 to 64, lets say in the example columns A, B and C but I want to ignore column ID. So it should look like this:

```
   ID A  B  C 
   2  5  5  5
   3  5  5  NA
```

I tried the following code, but it leaves me with an empty dataframe

```
features <- names(dat)[3:64] # define vector with column names to be filtered at
dat <- dat %>%
  filter_at(vars(features), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Someone has an idea why or how to solve this in a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `if_all` to remove (`!`) rows that are *all* `NA` between index 3 and 64. Also, note that `filter_at` is superseded by the use of `if_any` and `if_all`.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  filter(!(if_all(3:64, is.na)))
```

In your example, this translates to:

```r
dat %>% 
  filter(!(if_all(2:4, is.na)))

#  ID A B  C
#1  2 5 5  5
#2  3 5 5 NA
```

Comment: definitely the way to go here, +1

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `rowMeans`

```
dat[rowMeans(is.na(dat[3:64]))<1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should remove all rows which are completely NA:

```
dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) != ncol(dat), ]
```